# Looping through JSON data and display them dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, loops

I'm looping through JSON data but when I display the data I don't think the quality of the code is good enough, I feel like I'm doing something wrong.

```js
$(function(){
    $.getJSON('data.json', function(data){
        let content = '';

        for(let x in data){
            content += data[x]
        }
        $('.account-image').eq(0).attr('src', data[0].logo)
        $('.account-image').eq(1).attr('src', data[1].logo)
        $('.account-image').eq(2).attr('src', data[2].logo)
        $('.account-image').eq(3).attr('src', data[3].logo)
        $('.account-image').eq(4).attr('src', data[4].logo)
        $('.account-image').eq(5).attr('src', data[5].logo)
        $('.account-image').eq(6).attr('src', data[6].logo)
        $('.account-image').eq(7).attr('src', data[7].logo)
    })
})
```

Is there a way to loop through the `$(.account-image)` like the one written above but dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```js
$(function() {
  $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
    let content = '';

    for (let x in data) {
      content += data[x];
      $('.account-image').eq(x).attr('src', data[x].logo)
    }
  })
})
```